# websockets firefox on close or refresh

Tags: firefox, node.js, websocket

I am playing around writing a websocket server in node.js.  When testing in firefox, on refresh or page close, firefox seems to be sending random data, I have my server writing the data to std out and it seems to be different non printable characters every time.  Is this really random data, or something I am just no aware of.  I haven't been able to find any information on the closing handshake on websockets, but surely there must be something about this data.

Comment: It sounds like it isn't being unmasked properly. What are you using for websockets; socket.io?

Comment: Im writing my own server for websockets using node.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Websockets `CLOSE` frame](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.5.1) includes a two-byte network-order integer and an optional "descriptive" portion that need not be human readable. If you're writing the two-byte integer to standard out and treating it as two ASCII characters or UTF-8 characters, chances are good it'll just look like garbage.

Comment: on reload it appears the 'descriptive' portions changes every time, but the causation is the same, so shouldn't the description be the same.

Comment: Don't forget to unmask it. All client to server messages are masked even ping/pongs and close frames.